# SQL Server Full backup Log backup

Tags: sql-server

I have a question regarding Maximum File size MB for log files in our production database.

We are doing database server backup to cloud every night and log backup every 10 mins and our databases setup as Full recovery.

since the log backup's doesn't clear the disk space what are the recommended settings for a log file in FUll recovery database.

currently i set initial size 200 MB and max size 2400 MB instead of default 2TB Maximum file size auto growth setting.

once SQL server reaches its maximum log size is is going to use the free space in the log since we do log backups every 10 mins it always have unused space. how does File growth works. any chance this setup create an issue by not auto increase log after 2400 MB.

Log file set to inital size 200 MB and max size 2400 MB.

Comment: Where did you pull these numbers from? Are you using historical t-log backups to determine sizing?

Comment: SELECT DB_NAME() AS DbName, 
    name AS FileName, 
    type_desc,
    size/128.0 AS CurrentSizeMB,  
    size/128.0 - CAST(FILEPROPERTY(name, 'SpaceUsed') AS INT)/128.0 AS FreeSpaceMB
FROM sys.database_files
WHERE type IN (0,1);


Results:
DbName FileName type_desc CurrentSizeMB FreeSpaceMB
SPP_App SPP_App_Data ROWS 296293.062500 53890.250000
SPP_App SPP_App_Log LOG 205.562500 194.304688

I ran above query to find my log file size and added 2400 MB to be safe.

Comment: Since you are taking t-log backups frequently that should keep the log file growth in check. "once SQL server reaches its maximum log size is is going to use the free space in the log since we" - If the max size is reached, or there is not enough free space to commit a transaction, users will get sql errors. One thing to consider is what would happen if a super big transaction came through right after a 10-minute transaction log backup/truncate. I would set the maximum size much, much  higher to handle the unexpected.

Comment: what should be the initial size of log. it should be like 10% of the database size?

Comment: Pre-sizing is unique and should be loosely based on the volume of data and, in this case, the number of transactions and the average transaction size over a timespan. It is important because the aim is to reduce the number of auto-growth events to zero. You might want to ask these questions over at the DBA Exchange to get more thought-out answers. However, you want the initial size to be a reasonable value that will never be reached.